# Ruby on rails: Paperclip & Ruby Mp3Info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to upload an MP3 file (using the paperclip plugin) and then read the MP3 info (using the Mp3Info gem) right away so I can get the title, song length etc.

I can successfully upload a MP3 file using paperclip, but when I try Mp3Info.open(@song.music.url), I get an error saying the file is empty. Is there a proper reference to a file so that the Mp3Info can find the file?

(Note the actual file sits in /public/system/musics/:id/original/:filename.extention)

```
ActionView::TemplateError (empty file) on line #5 of app/views/songs/_upload.erb:

5: <%  Mp3Info.open( @song.music.url ) do |mp3|  %>
6:  <% mp3.tag.title %>
7: <% end %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try the "path" method instead of "url"

```
@song.music.path
```

Answer (score 0):

atropanic is right. Use `@song.music.path`!

Here is why: The URL is useless in this context, because Mp3Info expects a local file.

Comment: He is using paperclip to upload and if u put the bang !, u will get undifined method path! Cos it is a paperclip attatchment